# ¿Cómo obtener el token que es devuelto por mi API en Angular 5?

Tags: http, angular4, restful, cors

Estoy haciendo un request a un servicio rest desde Angular 5 a la ruta login, para que me devuelva un JWT en el header, de esta forma (Método getUserToken) :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams }  from "@angular/http";


import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';

import Config from '../../config/config';

@Injectable()
export class LoginServiceService {
  private url: string = Config.serviceRoute;
  headers: Headers;
  options: RequestOptions;

  constructor(private http:Http) { 
    this.headers = new Headers({ 'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': "*",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Custom-header",
                              });
    this.options = new RequestOptions({ headers: this.headers });
  }

  getUserToken(test){
    console.log("calling /login");
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'login', test, this.options)
      .map(res => {
        let headers = res.headers;
        let varaible = headers.get("Authorization");
        console.log("My varaible ", varaible);
        return res.json;
      });
  }
}
```

Pero cuando exploro el console.log de MiToken veo que está en nulo. Según entiendo por medidas de seguridad hay cosas a las que no puedo acceder en header, pero en este caso ¿Cómo puedo obtener el value que tiene Authorization?

Lo que me devuelve el API es esto en el header:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Host, Referer, Connection, User-Agent, Authorization, sw-useragent, sw-version
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbiIsImV4cCI6MTUxNjM3MTY5OX0.DDUF4gb0kXIZP17hFWYUqEVkeT9H0LZDOv4DKxgyktObV60klJhrzrBtv9m5UqWx6lZA0eZzIM1hn9nGp-_bnQ
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 19 Jan 2018 14:11:39 GMT
```

Actualización:

Cuando hago un console.log() del header me trae esto.

```
{"Cache-Control":["no-cache"," no-store"," max-age=0"," must-revalidate"],"Expires":["0"],"Pragma":["no-cache"]}
```

Por alguna razón no veo la authorization, que si veo desde el Mozilla o Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta misma pregunta la respondí en [SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45482346/1919228):

Cuando usas CORS, hay ciertos headers que tienen que añadirse en las respuestas. Tu respuesta tiene los siguientes:

- `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` Indica que cualquiera puede hacer peticiones.
- `Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, DELETE, PUT, OPTIONS` Indica qué métodos puedes usar.
- `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, ... Authorization, sw-useragent, sw-version` indica qué headers puedes **enviar** al servidor.

Ahora lo que te falta es el siguiente:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization
```

Este header define qué headers de los que manda el servidor **se pueden leer** y no está presente en tu respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, esta es la solución a mi problema.